# AngularJS is global when loaded with requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, require

I've set up the require config like this:

```
require.config({

    paths: {
        'angular': 'bower_components/angular/angular',
        'ui.router': 'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router'
    },

    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'ui.router': {
            deps: ['angular']
        }
    },

    deps: [
        'bootstrap'
    ]

});
```

When this is run, it seems like angular is available at `window.angular`, should that be so? In this case, I wouldn't even really need to add it as an dependency when using requirejs.

I've tried changing the `angular` key to `ng`, and specify `ng` as a dependeny, but then it can't find `ng` at all. `window.angular` is still available though.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is made available at `window.angular` when it is loaded, just like any other library.